# Page with form fields of 2 different forms "interweaven"

Tags: symfony, twig

I have the following issue, and I don't see what I’m doing wrong.
So I have a page (Symfony 6) where, in one controller, I handle 2 forms for one page (one is to upload/handle files, and the other one is for adding other fields and doing the “final submit”). It have to be 2 separate forms because at the back-end different procedures are called for the handling of the file /fields.

When I put all the form fields for the one form and then all the form fields for the second form in two different blocks where one block is entirely before/after the other one, both of the save buttons work.
When I however “intermingle” the two form fields then the save button of the “main” form doesn't work. Inspecting the HTML page doesn’t really reveals a lot.
So this works:

```
<div>
    {{ form_start(form, { 'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate', 'autocomplete': 'chrome-off', 'class': 'needs-validation'} }) }}
    <h2>{{ template['REF_NAME'] }}</h2>
    {{ form_row(form.remark) }}
    {{ form_row(form.save, {'attr':{ 'style':'height: 3em; margin-top: 38px','class':'py-0 btn btn-success'}}) }}
    {{ form_row(form._token) }}
    {{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}
</div>
<div>
    {{ form_start(formannex, { 'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate', 'autocomplete': 'chrome-off', 'class': 'needs-validation'} }) }}
    {{ form_row(formannex.annex) }}
    {{ form_widget(formannex.save, {'attr':{'style':'height: 2em; margin-top: 38px','class':'py-0 btn btn-primary'}}) }}
    {{ form_row(formannex._token) }}
    {{ form_end(formannex, {'render_rest': false}) }}
</div>
```

And for this one the “form.save”  does not work.

```
<div>
    {{ form_start(form, { 'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate', 'autocomplete': 'chrome-off', 'class': 'needs-validation'} }) }}
        <h2>{{ template['REF_NAME'] }}</h2>
        {{ form_row(form.remark) }}
            <div>
                {{ form_start(formannex, { 'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate', 'autocomplete': 'chrome-off', 'class': 'needs-validation'} }) }}
                {{ form_row(formannex.annex) }}
                {{ form_widget(formannex.save, {'attr':{'style':'height: 2em; margin-top: 38px','class':'py-0 btn btn-primary'}}) }}
                {{ form_row(formannex._token) }}
                {{ form_end(formannex, {'render_rest': false}) }}
            </div>
    {{ form_row(form.save, {'attr':{ 'style':'height: 3em; margin-top: 38px','class':'py-0 btn btn-success'}}) }}
    {{ form_row(form._token) }}
    {{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}
</div>
```

am I missing something obvious?

Comment: This is not allowed to merge form like that in html, howewer with symfony you can create multiple submit button for one form. And in your action you can check which button is clicked and do your own logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of Charlie Lucas is indeed 100% correct and should be an accepted answer (but I cannot choose a comment as answer). This link also helped me out: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html